# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate structuring modules

Tags: intellij-idea

I bought IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate last week and I'm totally amazed by this IDE. The only feature I'm missing at the moment are folders to sort, order and structure my modules (and I guess it is only because I'm too stupid to find it). E.g. I want to put some related modules into a folder or something.

Is there some kind of feature?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/grouping-modules.html , did you have a look at these?

Comment: @Akshay Gosh, I didn't find this for gods sake!

Comment: @Akshay Would you please create an answer so that I can give you the credit you reserve?

Comment: @bash0r -- Welcome to SO. Please read both [ask] and [answer]